# What is the exact species used for the canned magic beans?

Tags: houseplants

I got a *magic bean* in a tin can, which is basically just (some kind of) a bean placed in dry [Vermiculite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermiculite), and when opened and adding some water it starts grwing. However, out of the thousands of places its' available, nowhere does it say what plant species this bean belong to.

Here's a picture:

[image]

**What is the exact species of these?**

---

Thanks to alephzero's answer, I found more info here:

- https://www.feedipedia.org/node/326
- https://sites.google.com/site/efloraofindia/species/a---l/f/fabaceae/canavalia/canavalia-gladiata
- https://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/showimage/56333/
- https://sheffields.com/seeds/Canavalia/gladiata/

However, the trunk/stalk of the one I have doesn't quite look like it belong to *Canavalia Gladiata*. The answer also doesn't address the issue of the different colors of the beans.

Comment: "The answer also doesn't address the issue of the different colors" - It does now. I found your feedipedia link independently and that mentions the colour range - maybe you didn't read all of it!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on seasoned advice

Comment: @blackthumb I don't understand. What is the problem?

Comment: it's a food question, not a growing question

Comment: Not at all. It's for growing those magic beans that people give to kids. But the species of these cans are never clearly disclosed, which is why I came here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are *Canavalia Gladiata*, common name the Swordbean from the shape of the bean pods. The messages are laser-etched onto the seeds.

See https://thepatentmagicplant.com/message-bean/.

The beans are eaten as a vegetable in parts of Asia and India.

[This link](https://www.feedipedia.org/node/326) says that cultivated varieties of *C. Gladiata* have seeds with a range of colours from black through brown and red to white.

Some of the cultivars may have been crossed with a related species *C. ensiformis* (the jack bean) which has white seeds. The two species have always been distinguished by botanists, but genetically they are almost identical.

Comment: Looks promising, but what about the different colors? Also the stalk I have is not at all as thick as on the various pictures of that species.

Comment: Thank you for extra info.